# String Manipulation - Replace certain characters

Tags: linux, bash, sed

A linux command I have outputs a list of files that look like this:

```
    folder/folder/folder/file_1
    folder_1/folder/folder/file2
```

I want to format this output so the following conditions are met:

- The last slash (/) is always replaced with three underscores
- Every slash except the last slash is replaced with one underscore
- Any underscore in a folder name is replaced with two underscores
- Any underscore in a filename is left the way it is

The above would look like:

```
    folder_folder_folder___file_1
    folder__1_folder_folder___file2
```

If you could also explain your solution that would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Is this homework of some sort? The exercise seems rather pointless

Comment: No. I am just not that familiar with bash or linux in general. It serves a purpose - helping me automate something that would instead take 10-20 minutes if I did it by hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# Assume each line in a variable called $value
# Split the values up into dirname and basename
val_dir="${value%/*}"
val_base="${value##*/}"

# Replace underscores in dirname with two underscores
val_dir="${val_dir//_/__}"
# Replace slashes in dirname with single underscore
val_dir="${val_dir//\//_}"

# Re-join dirname and basename with three underscores
result="${val_dir}___${val_base}"
```

Answer (score 1):

an awk solution:

```
awk '
  BEGIN {FS="/";OFS="_"}
  {for (i=1; i<NF; i++) gsub("_","__",$i); $NF="__" $NF; print}
'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way you could do it with sed (tested with GNU sed):

```
<infile rev | sed -r 'h; s,_,__,g; G; s,[^/]+/([^\n]+)\n([^/]+/).*,\2\1,; :a; s,/,_,2; ta; s,/,___,' | rev
```

Output:

```
folder_folder_folder___file_1
folder__1_folder_folder___file2
```

`rev` makes it easier to parse, all it does is reverse the order of the characters on the line. I'll break down the sed script below:

```
h;                                  # save a copy of PS in HS, prepare to replace folder underscores
s,_,__,g;                           # replace folder underscores 
G;                                  # append HS to PS
s,[^/]+/([^\n]+)\n([^/]+/).*,\2\1,; # reorder into correct order
:a;
s,/,_,2;                            # replace most / with _, leave the first alone
ta;
s,/,___,                            # replace the first / with ___
```